# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when sending mail using Apache James 3

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, james, mime4j

I just downloaded and setup the Apache James 3 latest beta release on Windows and so far i haven't been able to send a simple message. It looks like there is an issue with the build. The error is -

```
ERROR 22:45:01,666 | james.mailspooler | Exception processing mail while spooling Unable to process mail Mail1442234701295-757cd62b-eeed-4671-828c-2a7c715acfaa (org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[Message: org.apache.james.core.MailImpl@4262d5d7])
javax.mail.MessagingException: Unable to process mail Mail1442234701295-757cd62b-eeed-4671-828c-2a7c715acfaa (org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[Message: org.apache.james.core.MailImpl@4262d5d7])
.
.
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Unable to process mail Mail1442234701295-757cd62b-eeed-4671-828c-2a7c715acfaa (org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[Message: org.apache.james.core.MailImpl@4262d5d7])
.
.
Caused by: org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[Message: org.apache.james.core.MailImpl@4262d5d7]
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.james.mime4j.stream.MimeConfig: method <init>()V not found
```

The relevant class in the JAR shows the supposedly missing constructor so i am at a complete loss. Can anyone guide me in the right direction please?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Decompiled code snippet from the MimeConfig class shows the constructor

```
public final class MimeConfig {
  /* member class not found */
  class Builder {}
.
.
  MimeConfig(boolean strictParsing, int maxLineLen, int maxHeaderCount, int maxHeaderLen, long maxContentLen, boolean countLineNumbers, 
                String headlessParsing, boolean malformedHeaderStartsBody) {
/*  53*/        this.strictParsing = strictParsing;
/*  54*/        this.countLineNumbers = countLineNumbers;
/*  55*/        this.malformedHeaderStartsBody = malformedHeaderStartsBody;
/*  56*/        this.maxLineLen = maxLineLen;
/*  57*/        this.maxHeaderCount = maxHeaderCount;
/*  58*/        this.maxHeaderLen = maxHeaderLen;
/*  59*/        this.maxContentLen = maxContentLen;
/*  60*/        this.headlessParsing = headlessParsing;
        }
```

Comment: Posting your code will help people understand it more clearly.

Comment: "The relevant class in the JAR shows the supposedly missing constructor" <-- how, specifically, did you verify this?

Comment: It's not my code, i just created users and sent mail per the Quickstart guide https://james.apache.org/server/3/quick-start.html

Comment: @DavidP.Caldwell I looked at the source code..

Comment: The source code may not be a valid guide here, unless you built the source code yourself and did not use some kind of binary distribution. See if you can examine the relevant classes with the `javap` command.

Comment: True. I also decompiled the class in my installation and it looked alright. I'll add the snippet tomorrow.

Comment: I did some research on the "method <init>()V not found" errors. It seems to me that If the constructor is not public, it could result in that error like when instantiating an object.

Comment: The decompiled class doesn't seem to have it public, but the source code sure does - http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.james/apache-mime4j-core/0.7.2/org/apache/james/mime4j/stream/MimeConfig.java

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and was searching for an answer. The error is because MimeConfig doesn't have a default constructor. I could get the mail successfully delivered locally by doing to following.

1. Dowloaded apache-mime4j-core-0.8.0-20150617.024907-738-sources
2. Created a default public constructor for MimeConfig
3. Initialized all the variables with values shown in the static class Builder constructor
4. Added setters for all the variables (Because I was getting NoSuchMethodError for setMaxLineLen)
5. Created a jar called apache-mime4j-0.8.0-fix.jar and pushed into the lib folder
6. I use run.sh, so replaced the mime4j core jar name with the above one.

I am sure there is some mismatch between spooler and mime4j. I think the calling code should use the Builder instead of directly trying to instantiate the MimeConfig.

Try these and let me know if it works. It worked for me. I am not sure if this is a permanent fix, but I can go ahead with exploring the V3 features till we get a permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the : **apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar** and **apache-mime4j-dom-0.7.2.jar**

download the two jars and put them in : james-server-app-3.0.0-beta5-SNAPSHOT\lib.

You can download james-server-app-3.0.0-beta5 from : https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/james/james-server-app/3.0.0-beta5-SNAPSHOT/.